# how to use datables server side processing with datatables knockout extension?

Tags: knockout.js, datatables

I am using the datatables knockout extension from here:https://github.com/CogShift/Knockout.Extensions

Im trying to retrieve the json from the server by making an ajax request and then making the array observable.
however it says that aaData is undefined.

My table definition:

```
 <table id="table" data-bind="dataTable: { 
            dataSource: getData, 
            aaData:observableArray,           
            columns: [
                'Column1', 
                'Column2', 
                'Column3', 
                { mDataProp: 'IsSelected', bSortable: false }
            ]
        }">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                    <td>Column 3</td>
                    <td>Select All <input type="checkbox" name="chkSelectAll" data-bind="checked: selectAll"  /></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

this is the ajax call :

```
this.getData = function (options, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Contact',
                data: ko.toJSON(options),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    for (key in responseData) {
                        var item = {
                            id:responseData[key].categoryid,
                            name: responseData[key].categoryname,         // Push the key on the array
                            value: responseData[key].description // Push the key's value on the array
                        };
                        self.dataArray.push(item);
                    }
                    $('#table').dataTable().fnAddData(self.observableArray());


                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you using 1.9.1 or earlier? The extension does not work with newer versions of datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use version 1.9.1 newer versions does not work.
You should use the callback instead of manally adding data

like

```
callback({
    Data: result,
    TotalRecords: count,
    DisplayedRecords: displayedCount
});
```

I have made some fixes to that extender found here.
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Extensions
Biggest change is that it let you access the data tables object decoupled from the DOM